# Drag and Drop Listview item into new seperate area from drawer

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, I have a list of all the user's installed applications set up in a listview in a sliding drawer. How can allow the user to drag one link from the listview into the other area of the drawer (the area the drawer pulls out onto)?

I've looked into drag and drop and I noticed that each item would need an ID (which I can't figure out how to create an id for each item).

Well anyways, here is my coding:

Drag_and_Drop_App:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Drag_and_Drop_App extends Activity {
private ListView mListAppInfo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);

    // load list application
    mListAppInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
    // create new adapter
    AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), getPackageManager());
    // set adapter to list view
    mListAppInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
    // implement event when an item on list view is selected
    mListAppInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // get the list adapter
            AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            // get selected item on the list
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
            // launch the selected application
            Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Please note that I have other class that run in the background to collect the users applications and run onClickListners, but this is what shows up in the actual widget.

Here is the Drag_and_Drop_App.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvApps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
/>


    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am aware that I would probably want to use a OnLongClick Listener so that when a item in the Listview is longclicked, the user can drag and drop it to the other section of the view.

I am also aware that the view the link/application would be dropped to would be one giant droptarget using the DragListener. (I've been looking at the tutorial on drag and drop [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)

How could I create an ID for each listview item so that it could have an assigned LongTouchListener to be used in the layout?

I hope this makes sense, if it doesn't please let me know!

Comment: Looking at it now...couldn't I just set a "setOnItemLongClickListener" in my Drag_and_Drop_App.java and then follow the Drag process from there? (still have the issue of assigning an ID though..)